# scp error: unexpected filename . / n00b dealing with Chef on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, scp, rsa, chef

I am very new to the Ops world, like really really new so often what I do might feel like copy/pasting and I wouldn't know what command means what and what an argument is, so please bear with my ignorance and lack of knowledge.

I am trying to deploy a Chef environment (just testing) on 2 VMs, Ubuntu 20.04 both, so I could later see how to add nodes/clients to the system and understand everything better. Now to the point.

1 VM is for Chef InfraServer the other one is for Chef Workplace. In order for me to configure **Knife** I need to pull the RSA private key from Chef Server to Chef Workplace.

This is the command I was given. What I have here, doesn't work for me.

```
$ scp chef-server:/home/chefadmin.pem .
```

This how my command looks.

```
sudo scp -r chef@10.0.2.15: /home/chef/chefadmin.pem /home/workspace/chef-repo/.chef
```

-r is there because without it I get *'No such file or directory'* or *scp: .: not a regular file*. 'chef' is the username on the Chef Server, then /workspace/chef-repo/.chef is the place that I am and where I have to import it.

What I get after hitting Enter.

```
chef@10.0.2.15's password:
error: unexpected filename: .
```

I have no idea why and don't ask me how I got there. I was watching tutorials and my job apparently is to pull the validator key to the Workplace station.

There is ssh between them, they can see each other and communicate via NAT Networking, so that one thing I fixed at least.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be no space after `:`, unless you really want `chef@10.0.2.15:` which is interpreted as `chef@10.0.2.15:.`, i.e. the `.` directory on the server.

Comment: Thank you! This was definitely the answer. Sadly I am very new to all of this and don't know why things are the way they are. I thought that I solved a problem by adding space since I got another result, but apparently later that was the actual problem. I tried what both of you described here and it helped!